# Theory: Can JIT Compiler be used to parse the whole program first, then execute later?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, theory, interpreter, jit

Normally, JIT Compiler works by reads the byte code, translate it into machine code, and execute it. This is what I understand, but in theory, is it possible to make the JIT Compiler parses the whole program first, then execute the program later as machine code? I do not know how JIT Compiler works technically and exactly, so I don't know any feasibility in this case. But theoretically, is it possible? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, for the simple reason that "JIT" means "Just-In-Time" and if you don't do it "Just-In-Time", then it's not a "Just-In-Time" compiler.

That's like asking whether it would be possible to buy a red car, but in blue.

What you are asking for, is an Ahead-Of-Time compiler, which is usually just called a compiler.

Answer (score 4):

As Mehrdad said, it's no longer a JIT compiler, but yes, you can compile ahead of time.  In .NET they have a tool called [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which does just this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but it's usually not called JIT compilation anymore. It's essentially ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation.